# How to know cellular provider by a given IP?

Tags: mobile, network-programming, gprs, cellular-network

Is there any web service / API / other way to figure out a cellular Internet provider / carrier (id / name / anything else) for a given mobile browser request? Both client-side and server-side solutions will be acceptable. For example, maybe there is something similar to determining an location by IP (just count a carrier instead).

If the tags of this question aren't correct - please advice. If there is any other site worth checking - please share the appropriate URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://www.maxmind.com/, their database of IP info provides both geo location and MNO (Mobile Network Operator) provider. You can test by going to their home page and putting in the IP of your phone. Of course, if a phone is connected using WiFi you won't get the MNO.

You need to get the ISP database. http://www.maxmind.com/app/isp

Comment: Also searched through several other geo-tagging providers. They all are providing nearly the same level of service.